# Fragment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gridview, adapter

I am trying to insert a GridView which is populated from my SQLite Database, but I am getting the error

"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference"

**MyAdapter.java** class

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Players> playerList;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Players> playerList){
    this.context = context;
    this.playerList = playerList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return playerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_grid_item, null);

    TextView idTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_id);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_name);
    TextView roleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_role);

    Players p = new Players();
    p = playerList.get(position);
    idTextView.setText("ID " + String.valueOf(p.getId()));
    nameTextView.setText("Name " + String.valueOf(p.getName()));
    roleTextView.setText("Role " + String.valueOf(p.getRole()));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

**GameActivity.java** Class

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

}

public void FragmentOneClick(View view) {
    Fragment myfragment;
    myfragment = new RolesFragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, myfragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

**RolesFragment.java**

```
public class RolesFragment extends Fragment {

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Players> playersList;
MyAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewroles, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gv_players);

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    playersList = new ArrayList<Players>();

    playersList = databaseHelper.getPlayers();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), playersList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is  `getView()` returns null.

in fragment you have to use: fragment's `view` instance.

so instead of:

```
gridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gv_players);
```

use:

```
 gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv_players);
```

Comment: Ofcourse!! Thank you very much, it is now working after hours of playing about with the code.

Comment: @TussRamzan if the answer works...mark it as correct. Thankx